# Fluent Interface, Need something like global methods in C#

Tags: c#, fluent-interface, global-methods

Im currently trying to build a Fluent Interface for a ServiceLocator. To ensure that each the developer can easily setup 1-to-n mappings

I'd like something like this

```
ServiceLocator.Instance.For<IFoo>(Use<Foo>(), Use<FooBar>());
```

Singleton is workin fine... the methodsignature for the For method looks like this

```
public void For<TInterface>(params type[] services)
{
// ... 
}
```

So I was looking for something like a **global method**

C# has some global methods, all methods which are defined on System.Object. But when I create a new generic ExtensionMethod on System.Object, the method will not be visible.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static void Use<T>(this Object instance)
  {
    // ..
  }
}
```

MethodChaining would be the alternative, but this approach looks sexy :D

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: A feature called "static using" has been requested several times (basically, to allow `static using System.Math; x = Sqrt(area) / PI * Cos(theta); y = Sqrt(area) / PI * Sin(Theta);` instead of `x = Math.Sqrt(area) / Math.PI * Math.Cos(theta); y = Math.Sqrt(area) / Math.PI * Math.Sin(theta)`, but so far the C# team hasn't listened.  The original objection was that it breaks OOP, but C# no longer is a purely OO language.  If enough people keep pestering the C# team about this, we should eventually get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually when I create an extension method for `Object`, it is visible. As in,

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void doStuff<T>(this T myObject)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 5;
        a.doStuff();

        string b = "aaa";
        b.doStuff();

        List<int> c = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 10 };
        c.doStuff();

        Extensions.doStuff(c);        
    }
}
```

Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: ok, but try a generic one.
And try to call it globally like Equals(Object,Object)

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example involving a generic type and a global call to the extension method. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not the hosting Type have to be generic, the ExtensionMethod should be generic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `using` statement for the namespace containing your extension method in order for it to be visible. Adding extension methods to `object` is rarely a good idea.

EDIT:
Okay, now I understand what you're asking. In order to use an extension method you need an instance. You're asking for a static extension method on object (Equals and ReferenceEquals are [static methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)), and that's not possible. If you define an extension method on object, it will be available on all instances and I'm sure that's not what you want.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string TypeFullName(this object obj)
    {
        return obj.GetType().FullName;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = new object();
    Console.WriteLine(obj.TypeFullName());

    var s = "test";
    Console.WriteLine(s.TypeFullName());
}
```

Comment: using is included...

I know about the disadvantage of creating extension methods on system.object. I just would like to figure out if my idea is working.

Answer (score 1):

[Service Locator is widely considered to be an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). Also, a common registration interface is widely considered to be an unsolvable problem unless you are requiring use of a specific container.

Looking past these two questionable decisions, you can remove the need for the global method by defining overloads of `For` which accept multiple type arguments:

```
ServiceLocator.Instance.For<IFoo, Foo, FooBar>();
```

The `For` methods would look like this:

```
public void For<TInterface, TImplementation>()

public void For<TInterface, TImplementation1, TImplementation2>()

...
```

You have to define an overload for each type count, but it requires the minimal syntax and maximum amount of discoverability. For reference, the .NET Framework's `Action` and `Func` types support 9 type arguments.

After writing this out, though, I wonder if I misunderstood the question: why would you specify multiple implementations for the same interface? Wouldn't that lead to ambiguity when resolving `IFoo`?

Comment: Yes overloading is an option, but It will mess up the class. ServiceLocator is just a sample here.... I know the disadvantages...